# Reputation misaligned in new topbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, firefox

In the sites dropdown, the reputation scores are misaligned:

[image]

This seems to happen only on Firefox (56.0), both on macOS (10.13) and Windows (7, 10) (thanks @Tom and @MonicaCellio). I've tested a couple of other browsers which do not have this problem. I've already cleared my cache.

Comment: Also FF 58 on Windows 7 (unsprising given that it happens on Win10, but for the sake of completeness...)

Comment: Removing `white-space: nowrap` from `.topbar-dialog .modal-content li > a` seems to fix it. Was this part changed in the last update?

Comment: *They align fine in your screenshot* ... oh wait ... horizontal ... that happens without red free hand circles ...

Comment: @rene https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztygG.png doesn't make it any clearer IMHO.

Comment: that's why we use chrome

Comment: @redhand I can’t, my sockpuppet is logged in on Chrome.

Comment: @Glorfindel, use edge for sock (as I do)

Comment: @Bumblebee on macOS?

Comment: ah you're on mac? what about safari?

Comment: I use that, too, but it doesn’t support userscripts. But ... let’s not use comments for things they aren’t meant for.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too (Firefox 52.3, Windows 10).

Comment: I thought they had thoroughly tested this so-called improved top bar on Stack Overflow for about a year. What was the point of doing that, I wonder, if they are going to add strange bugs in network-wide release.

Comment: Happens on Firefox 54 Linux, too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. I have pushed a fix internally, and now waiting for the next build for the fix to be published across the network.

Should be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in couple hours.